# What all file metadata is available in macOS?

Tags: macos, filesystem, metadata

I have gone through Windows versioning information: [Please Check out Windows file versioning information](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/win32/versioning/article.php/c4539/Versioning-in-Windows.htm)

Now Windows provide quite an ample amount of information like productname, productversion, CompanyName, Comments, FileDescription and so on.

I went through `mdls` command and that information is very less compare to what Windows provide.

Does anyone have idea how to get equivalent information for Mac OS's (preferably in Sierra & El-Capitan) files as well ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applications on macOS store similar types of metadata in `Info.plist` files stored within the application bundles themselves.

For example to see the metadata available for Safari you can run the following command in a Terminal window.

`plutil -p /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/Info.plist`

Or to get the version of Safari specifically you can run...

`plutil -p /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/Info.plist | grep CFBundleShortVersionString`

Comment: This does provide lot of needed information, Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

## While helpful, the accepted answer is incomplete.

- OP wanted a list of **all** *file metadata* in macOS.
- The question is valid, but an exhaustive list don't exist *afaik*, as the set of metadata attributes is dynamic.
- New keys are added e.g. whenever you install new software, and also appears to reflect which user is currently logged in.

#### 1.  The `mdls` man-page refers to the `mdfind` page under SEE ALSO:

```
$ man mdls
  (...)
  SEE ALSO
       mdfind(1), mdutil(1) xargs(1)
```

#### 2. Looking up the `mdfind` manual

```
$ man mdfind
  (...)
      To get a list of the available attributes for use in constructing queries, 
      see mdimport(1), particularly the -X switch.
```

#### 3. Querying `mdimport`

(today is December 24th,  2019 - on my desktop running `macOS 10.15.2 (19C57)`

```
$ mdimport -X
  (...)
Schema: id(501) {
    Attributes =     {
        MessageGUIDs =         {
            multivalued = 1;
            name = MessageGUIDs;
            nosearch = 1;
            type = CFString;
        };
        "_kMDItemDomainIdentifier" =         {
            multivalued = 0;
            name = "_kMDItemDomainIdentifier";
            nosearch = 1;
            notokenize = 1;
            type = CFString;
        };
        "_kMDItemUserTags" =         {
            multivalued = 1;
            name = "_kMDItemUserTags";
            nosearch = 1;
            type = CFString;
            uniqued = 1;
        };
        "com_DEVONtechnologies_think_DatabaseName" =         {
            multivalued = 0;
            name = "com_DEVONtechnologies_think_DatabaseName";
            type = CFString;
            uniqued = 1;
        };
  (...)
```

Comment: You started grand, but cut in the middle... finally using all these commands you enlist - how does one extract available metadata for specific file?

Comment: @MottiShneor I'm sorry, but I don't understand what is meant by the "grand (...) cut in the middle" reference. But to learn more about how to extract metadata and attributes for specific file, try ´man mdls xattr´in your shell. Either ´mdls´ or ´xattr´I believe will do what you want.